# calculate second largest salary

Tags: mysql, sql, count, subquery, where-clause

Can anyone help me to understand below query how its working ?

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employee A
WHERE n-1 = (SELECT count(1) 
             FROM employee B 
             WHERE B.salary>A.salary)
```

cusrious to know, the logical working of this.

Answer (score 1):

This query filters the dataset using a correlated subquery (that is, a query that refers to a column from the outer table). The correlation condition is:

```
WHERE B.salary > A.salary
```

So, the correlated subquery counts how many employees in the table have a salary that is greater than the salary on the current row.

Say you want the second greatest salary, then there should be exactly one employee with a greater salary. The `where` clause does the math.

Note that this might not behave as you would expect if there are ties. For example, if there are two employees with the same, top salary, then the query returns an empty resultset when given value `2` to parameter `n`.

Answer (score 0):

You have a great explanation by GMB. but You can use `LIMIT` for fetching the nth highest value in simplest way as follows:

```
SELECT name, salary
FROM employee A
Order by salary desc
LIMIT 1,1
```